# Argumentos de funciones en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo Python 3 para poder utilizarlo en mi proyecto de tesis de doctorado. He estado utilizando la documentación oficial para aprender sobre lo que las distintas funciones de Python hacen pero sigo sin entender que significa la parte entre los brackets `[]` en algunos de los argumentos que reciben las funciones. Para ser más específico, que significa `[, count]` en `str.replace(old, new[, count])`?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, disculpa, me confundí con el sitio en inglés, ya corregí el post.

Comment: Lo que está entre los brackets es una convención para indicar que el parámetro es opcional.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, muchas gracias. Esa convención se utiliza usualmente en otros lenguajes o solo en Python?

Comment: Más bien es una convención de la aplicación de documentación que usa Python http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/. No es algo que pueda considerarse un estándar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto la documentacion a la funcion replace: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)

El count viene siendo cuantas veces quieras que se cambie la palabra a buscar.

En este ejemplo sustituye "geeks" por "GeeksforGeeks" 3 veces

```
string = "geeks for geeks geeks geeks geeks" 
print(string.replace("geeks", "GeeksforGeeks", 3))
```

Creo que lo que te ha confundido es la ',' que viene a significar que ahí iría lo que tu quieres que se sustituya en el string

EDIT:

Como dice @Patricio Moracho y que se me olvido comentarte :

> count – the number of times you want to replace the old substring with
>   the new substring. (Optional )

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había entendido más que nada lo de que es opcional, por más que busqué no estaba por ningún lado.